# Trying to change the sidebar options name

Tags: vuejs2

DashboardLayout.vue;

```
<template slot="links">
        <sidebar-item
          :link="{
            name: $t('sidebar.dashboard'),
            icon: 'tim-icons icon-components',
            path: 'dashboard'
          }"
        >
        </sidebar-item>
        <sidebar-item
          :link="{ name: $t('sidebar.users'), icon: 'tim-icons icon-badge' }"
        >
          <sidebar-item
            :link="{ name: $t('sidebar.editors'), path: 'editors' }"
          ></sidebar-item>
          <sidebar-item
            :link="{
              name: $t('sidebar.reviewers'),
              path: 'reviewers'
            }"
          ></sidebar-item>
          <sidebar-item
            :link="{ name: $t('sidebar.authors'), path: 'authors' }"
          ></sidebar-item>
        </sidebar-item>
        <sidebar-item
          :link="{
            name: $t('sidebar.submissions'),
            icon: 'tim-icons icon-paper',
            path: 'submissions'
          }"
        ></sidebar-item>
        <sidebar-item
          :link="{
            name: $t('sidebar.reports'),
            icon: 'tim-icons icon-chart-pie-36',
            path: 'reports'
          }"
        ></sidebar-item>
      </template>
```

Router.js;

```
let ijire = {
  path: '/ijire',
  component: DashboardLayout,
  name: 'IJIRE',
  redirect: '/ijire/dashboard',
  children: [
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      name: 'IJIRE Dashboard',
      components: { default: Dashboard }
    },
    {
      path: 'authors',
      name: 'IJIRE Authors',
      components: { default: ExtendedTables }
    },
    {
      path: 'reviewers',
      name: 'IJIRE Reviewers',
      components: { default: ValidationForms }
    },
    {
      path: 'editors',
      name: 'IJIRE Editors',
      components: { default: RegularTables }
    },
    {
      path: 'submissions',
      name: 'IJIRE Submissions',
      components: { default: PaginatedTables }
    },
    {
      path: 'reports',
      name: 'IJIRE Reports',
      components: { default: Charts }
    }
  ]
}
```

sidebarItem.vue

```
<template>
  <component
  :is="baseComponent"
    :to="link.path ? link.path : '/'"
    :class="{ active: isActive }"
    tag="li"
  >
    <a
      v-if="isMenu"
      class="sidebar-menu-item"
      :aria-expanded="!collapsed"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      @click.prevent="collapseMenu"
    >
    <template v-if="addLink">
        <span class="sidebar-mini-icon">{{ linkPrefix }}</span>
        <span class="sidebar-normal">
          {{ link.name }} <b class="caret"></b>
        </span>
      </template>
      <template v-else>
        <i :class="link.icon"></i>
        <p>{{ link.name }} <b class="caret"></b></p>
      </template>
    </a>

    <collapse-transition>
      <div
        v-if="$slots.default || this.isMenu"
        v-show="!collapsed"
        class="collapse show"
      >
        <ul class="nav">
          <slot></slot>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </collapse-transition>

    <slot
      name="title"
      v-if="children.length === 0 && !$slots.default && link.path"
    >
      <component
        :to="link.path"
        @click.native="linkClick"
        :is="elementType(link, false)"
        :class="{ active: link.active }"
        :target="link.target"
        :href="link.path"
      >
        <template v-if="addLink">
          <!-- inside users dropdown -->
          <span class="sidebar-mini-icon">{{ linkPrefix }}</span>   
          <span class="sidebar-normal">{{ link.name }}</span>
        </template>
        <template v-else>
          <i :class="link.icon"></i>
          <p>{{ link.name }}</p>
        </template>
      </component>
    </slot>
  </component>
</template>
```

sidebar.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="sidebar" :data="backgroundColor">
    <div class="sidebar-wrapper" ref="sidebarScrollArea">

      <div class="jms-logo logo">[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        <!-- Ijire dropdown -->
        <el-select       
          size="large"
          placeholder="Select Journal"
          v-model="selects.simple"
          @change="changeJournal"
        >
          <el-option
            v-for="option in selects.journals"
            :value="option.value"
            :label="option.label"
            :key="option.label"
          >
          </el-option>
        </el-select>
      </div>
      <!--  end -->
      <ul class="nav">
        <slot name="links">
        </slot>
      </ul>
      <!-- end -->

    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

'Issue : This is my working project, I want to change the sidebar names(eg. dashboard, users,submission), here in dashboardlayout component it has mentioned like $t('sidebar.dashboard'), if I try to change the name dashboard to maincard means I'm getting the output like sidebar.maincard. I'm not getting only maincard it shows fully.. I dont know how to change the option names and the flow .. Kindly help me'

Comment: This is an i18n thing, check for a `locales` directory in your project, you should fine a `en.json` or alike there. You can update the `sidebar` + `dashboard` keys to what you want and have them identically translated into your views. PS: do that change to all the other locales too, or you will get some issues of non-matching keys as you can guess.

Comment: Mind if I post an answer?